# PHP code with variables not UPDATING MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie-ish to MySQL/PHP (using XAMPP).  I have tried every recommendation I have seen here for code but nothing seems to work....

I have a 3-column, 19 row table of textboxes (row1Field1, Row1, field2, row1Field3, etc.)

I am trying to UPDATE my database for those records where there will be records for each row (almost)

I KNOW THERE IS NO REAL SQL INJECTION PROTECTION.  That is not an issue at this point.  This is all opn my personal laptop & most likely will never see the Internet.

Here is my coe, 99% works everytime.  The UPDATE does not.

```
<?php require '../connect/connect.php';  //connects the db (10 pages so far - all works
// Start the session
session_start();
$wk2Use = $_SESSION["wk2Use"];
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <?php

        $f="";
        $s=0;
        $p=0;

        for($i=1; $i <= 19; $i++) {
            $f = "gm" . $i . "Fav";
            $s = "gm" . $i . "Sprd";
            $p = "gm" . $i . "Pts";
            $f = htmlspecialchars($_POST[$f]);
            $s = htmlspecialchars($_POST[$s]);
            $p = htmlspecialchars($_POST[$p]);

            if (!empty($f)) {
                //This displays the correct data!
                echo 'Wk-' . $wk2Use . '  ' . $f . ' ' . $s . ' ' . $p . '<br>';            


                //This does NOT work
                $sql = ("USE bbschdefs; UPDATE bbschdefs SET sSchFav='".$f."', sSchSprd=$s, sSchOUPts=$p 
                        WHERE ((sSchVTAbrv='".$f."' OR sSchHTAbrv='".$f."') AND schWk=$wk2Use )");
                $result = mysqli_query($dbconn,$sql);           
            }
        }   
        $i=0;

        include '../predictions/predict.php' 

        ?>

    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: what's the error output?

Comment: Does the browser shows any php error?

Comment: Opening `(` and closing `)` are superfluous. `USE bbschdefs;` should not be needed unless you are changing DB. There is also an extra set of `( )` in the `WHERE` clause that is unnecessary. `var_dump($sql)` and run it manually to see what is really going on.

Comment: Try to do one query at a time...

Comment: Using prepared statements would be beneficial for several reasons: 1) learn to do it the right way from the start, 2) reduce errors from going in and out of quote blocks ie “‘.$var.’” 3) it might even fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to guess it's because your variable `$wk2Use` is not properly being added to your where clause

`WHERE ((sSchVTAbrv='".$f."' OR sSchHTAbrv='".$f."') AND schWk=$wk2Use )`

Should be

`WHERE ((sSchVTAbrv='".$f."' OR sSchHTAbrv='".$f."') AND schWk='{$wk2Use}' )`

OR

`WHERE ((sSchVTAbrv='".$f."' OR sSchHTAbrv='".$f."') AND schWk='".$wk2Use."' )`

Comment: Neither   schWk='{$wk2Use}'  or schWk=' " . $wk2Use . " '  work - no difference.

Comment: I would just echo the SQL statement to the page to verify it's getting the correct values and go from there